# Compare individual to group

Tags: mysql

I am relatively new to MySQL. I have a huge database of salespeople and each sale they make, and for how much. I know that I can put AVG(SaleAmount) in a SELECT statement to get the average number of sales of the people at large, but I was wondering how I can get a list of each individuals' average sales, and then compare it to the group average to get a group of salesmen who are above that average.

I eventually want a list of those salespeople whose averages are two standard deviations above the group average.

I'm sorry if this is relatively simple, but I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you add your table structure?  Do you have just one table here, or are there two (`salesperson` and `sale` or is it just `salesperson`)

Comment: It is all in one table, with columns for salespeople, sale, and saleAmount. I'm not sure how to add a table structure though

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that gets the global statistics.

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, AVG(SaleAmount) AS personAvg, avgSale, stdSale
FROM salespeople AS s
JOIN (SELECT AVG(SaleAmount) AS avgSale, STDDEV(SaleAmount) AS stdSale
      FROM salespeople) AS av
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING personAvg > avgSale + 2 * stdSale
```